# Request authorization for remote notifications always return false at first start

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

request authorization for push notifications always return false when app is first loaded even user tap "allow" on dialog.
Here is function for register which is called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. At next launch granted is true.

```
func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else{return}
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything present in the `error` variable?

Comment: No error, just returns false. A bit weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register for remote notification within didfinishLaunchingWithOptions and make sure registered for remote notification.

> application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        guard granted else{return}

        self.getNotificationSettings()

    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we call requestAuthorization outside the didfinishLaunchingWithOptions. My requirement is to show the notification auth popup after enabling a switch after user opens the app (not to show immediately after app opens).

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in `didfinishLaunchingWithOptions` method,

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
         if granted {
         }
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (setttings) in

    switch setttings.soundSetting{
         case .enabled:
              print("enabled sound setting")

         case .disabled:
               print("setting has been disabled")

         case .notSupported:
               print("something vital went wrong here")
        }
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {
   let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound], categories: nil)
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
```

I hope it will help you out!